# Add red dot in a tab in navbar

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular6

I need to add a red dot with a number in a messaging tab when there are new messages.

This is my HTML

```
<ul class="nav pw-nav pw-nav--horizontal">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLink]="['/company/dashboard/home']">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLink]="['/company/dashboard/documents']">My Applications</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLink]="['/company/dashboard/registry']">Registered entities</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLink]="['/company/conversation']">Communication</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLink]="['/company/dashboard/external-services']">External Services</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLink]="['/company/dashboard/contact-us']">Contact us</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLink]="['/company/dashboard/user-manuals']">User Manuals</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link disabled">Post-Registration</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link disabled">How to</a>
    </li>
    <!--<li class="nav-item">-->
      <!--<a class="nav-link" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLink]="['/company/dashboard/post-registration']">Post-Registration</a>-->
    <!--</li>-->
    <!--<li class="nav-item">-->
      <!--<a class="nav-link" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLink]="['/company/dashboard/how-to']">How to</a>-->
    <!--</li>-->
  </ul>
```

this is my TS

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import {DashboardComponent} from './dashboard.component';
import {HomeComponent} from './home/home.component';
import {DocumentsComponent} from './documents/documents.component';
import {RegistryComponent} from './registry/registry.component';
import {ExternalServicesComponent} from './external-services/external-services.component';
import { ContactUsComponent } from './contact-us/contact-us.component';
import {HowToComponent} from './how-to/how-to.component';
import {PostRegComponent} from './post-registration/post-reg.component';
import {UserManualsComponent} from './user-mannuals/user-manuals.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'documents' },
      { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
      { path: 'documents', component: DocumentsComponent },
      { path: 'registry', component: RegistryComponent },
      { path: 'external-services', component: ExternalServicesComponent },
      { path: 'contact-us', component: ContactUsComponent },
      { path: 'user-manuals', component: UserManualsComponent },
      { path: 'post-registration', component: PostRegComponent },
      { path: 'how-to', component: HowToComponent }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class DashboardRoutingModule {}
```

I just an internship in a company and have never faced JS , Angular 6 before.
What I found in google is, I need to import badge.module and then in HTML add it.
However, I am not sure where to look for a file for importing the badge module.

Comment: If you are an intern - ask your supervisor for assistance. Never be afraid to ask for help. It seems unreasonable to just put a new intern onto a task and say" go fior it"... with no assistance or mentoring.

Comment: no problems for me and for them. However, I want to try first and then if it does not help, I go for a help

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [this](https://stackblitz.com/angular/ebmklqdbgla?file=src%2Fmain.ts) you can see a working example of material badges.

In this project they've imported all the modules and re-exported them for demo purposes. This module can then be added to the imports of your app.module.ts and will be globally available for your application.

If youre using Material only for badges then just `import {MatBadgeModule} from '@angular/material/badge';` after installing the requisite node modules.

Comment: Hello @Aditya

Thanks for the reply.
So, my teamlead said that they have the red dot already and as I can see in the code they have the thing to show numbers of new messages, however it is inside the page, while I need to add it into the header.

`<a class="nav-link" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLink]="['/company/conversation']">Communication</a>`


`const numberOfUnreadMessagesTimer = TimerObservable.create(0, 60000);
    this.checkUnreadMessagesTimerSubscription = numberOfUnreadMessagesTimer.subscribe(timer => {
      this.getNumberOfUnreadMessages();
    });`